# Set div to remaining height using CSS with unknown height divs above and below

Tags: html, css, height, scrollable

Is it possible to make the wrapper fill the window height (no scrolling) and the center div scrollable without messing around with pixels and javascript?

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <div id="center">
    <div style="height:1000px">high content</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Basically I want the header to be visible at the top and the footer to be always visible at the bottom and have a scrollable content in the center which occupies the remaning height.
The header, footer and center divs' heights are all unknown (no set px or %, i.e. variable font-size or padding). Is it possible with pure CSS?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish the same essential thing as in this question? Though variable heights would make it trickier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555157/full-screen-css-with-minimum-size/8555283#8555283

Comment: Similar but the layout without a fixed height header or footer, so changing the content of header or footer or adding elemets to them, won't affect the css properties of the center div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cross-browser solution derived from [Dan Dascalescu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242226/1105011) answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uc9E2

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.l-fit-height {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
.l-fit-height-row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 1px;
}
.l-fit-height-row-content {
    /* Firefox requires this */
    display: table-cell;
}
.l-fit-height-row-expanded {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
.l-fit-height-row-expanded > .l-fit-height-row-content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .l-scroll {
        /* Firefox requires this to do the absolute positioning correctly */
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
.l-scroll {
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 1000px;
}
.l-scroll-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 1000px;
    min-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="l-fit-height">
    <section class="l-fit-height-row">
        <div class="l-fit-height-row-content">
            <p>Header</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="l-fit-height-row-expanded">
        <div class="l-fit-height-row-content l-scroll">
            <div class="l-scroll-content">
                <p>Foo</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="l-fit-height-row">
        <div class="l-fit-height-row-content">
            <p>Footer</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be nice to have all those classes explained somewhat.

Answer (score 82):

**2014 UPDATE**: The modern way to solve this layout problem is to [use the `flexbox` CSS model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26558049/1269037). It's supported by all major browsers and IE11+.

---

2012: The correct way to do this with CSS alone is to use `display: table` and `display: table-row`. These are [supported by all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-table), starting with IE8. This is *not* using tables for display. You'll use divs:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;  /* just to make sure nothing bleeds */
}
.header {
    display: table-row;
    background: gray;
}
.content {
    display: table-row;  /* height is dynamic, and will expand... */
    height: 100%;        /* ...as content is added (won't scroll) */
    background: turquoise;
}
.footer {
    display: table-row;
    background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Header of variable height</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Content that expands in height dynamically to adjust for new content</h2>
        Content height will initially be the remaining
        height in its container (<code>.wrapper</code>).
        <!-- p style="font-size: 4000%">Tall content</p -->
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <h3>Sticky footer</h3>
        <p>Footer of variable height</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's it. The divs are wrapped as you'd expect.

Comment: I would like to add the following refinement: http://jsfiddle.net/6dbyr/

This allows to have a scrollable area inside the cell that takes up the full height.

Comment: Argh... and a big breaker, that refinement doesn't work in Firefox. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=794644

But this does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605816/sticky-flexible-footers-and-headers-css-working-fine-in-webkit-but-not-in-gecko/12622740#12622740

Comment: Note that content (if its height is bigger than the wrapper height) will overflow in IE (even IE10).

Comment: `display: table-row` will remove all the borders from the items it is applied to

Comment: After playing around with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605816/sticky-flexible-footers-and-headers-css-working-fine-in-webkit-but-not-in-gecko/12622740#12622740 got this working in all browsers except Opera: http://jsfiddle.net/Uc9E2/

Comment: Any chance to do this if the header element can't be touched (it already is display: table itself...)?

Comment: @danial this really helped me today, thank you very much. It now works in Opera too, since it's much similar to Chrome these days. I think you should answer yourself with this method, because I've been trying this and that, making up markup myself, googling, trying various solutions and only yours did what I need in every browser and even with zero changes to adapt it. This was very helpful fiddle that should get more attention.

Answer (score -2):

Using `overflow:auto` will let you do this.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5kyRA/)

Comment: In your example you set the height to 80%, but I don't know the height of the center div, I just want it to take the remaining space. Thanks

Comment: @danial, do you know the height of the footer and header?  (In percents or pixels)

Comment: no I don't, I just updated the question. It depends on the font-size, padding and/or other elements that might be added dynamically.

Comment: If it's possible, I don't know how to do it.  The usual approach here is to give the header, content, and footer each a percentage based size.

Comment: It can be done with `display: table` and `display: table-row`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12242226/1269037).

Answer (score -2):

So what you are talking about is a sticky footer.  I went and did some more research and here is what I have for you.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height:100%">
<div id="header" style="float:none;"><h1>Header</h1></div>

<div style="overflow:scroll;float:none;height:auto;">high content</div>

<div id="footer" style="clear:both;position:fixed;bottom:0px;"><h1>Footer</h1></div>
</div>
```

This will give you a sticky footer.  The key is position:fixed and bottom:0px;
Unfortunately this means it also hovers above any content in the scrollview.  So far there seems to be only Javascript to figure this out but I will keep looking.

Comment: And it seems from my research that the only way to do what you are asking is via javascript as css doesn't support referenced heights 'i.e height = (page.height - (header.height + footer.height)