# Set div to use remaining height using CSS with unknown height of other divs

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to implement solution similar to provided here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242226

The problem with it (for me) is that it does not allow to restrict height of inner div.
So I've updated solution as follows:

```
<style type='text/css'>
html, body {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
.component {
    display: table-row;
    background: gray;
}
.content {
    display: table-cell;  /* height is dynamic, and will expand... */
    height: 100%;        /* ...as content is added (won't scroll) */
    background: turquoise;
}

.contentRel {
    height: 100%;
        background: blue;
    position: relative;
}

.contentRemaining {
        background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top:30px;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}


  </style>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="component">
        <h1>Component</h1>
        <p>of variable height</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class='contentRel'>
            <div>100% Component Header</div>
        <div class='contentRemaining'>
            <div style='height:1000px'>
            100% Component Content
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="component">
        <h3>Other</h3>
        <p>componet of variable height</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UrcV7/

It works as I need in FF (height of contentRel div is set to 320px - height of wrapper div minus sum of heights of component divs), but doesn't work in IE: height of (contentRel div is set to 400px - same as height of wrapper div).
Does anybody know how to fix it?

Here is my problem description (maybe it is another solution for it):

1. I have an outer div with height set to some px values (wrapper div in example).
2. In that div I have several other divs which can be hidden dynamically by some JS code.
3. All divs except of 1 has some height. though it is unknown to me (component divs in example).

I want that one remaining div (content div in example) to:

a. Use all remaining height of wrapper div

b. Have a header of some predefined height (100% Component Header part in example above)

c. Have a child div with height "100% of content div" - "height of header" (100% Component Content in example above)

d. To not to be taller than "height of wrapper div minus sum of heights of component divs" (scrollbars are ok)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what your after, maybe it would be worth adding the explanation to your example. But if i'm right in thinking, you could just add `min-height: 100%;` to your `.component` `class`

Comment: No, the problem is not with div.component divs, but with div.content div. If you'll check my jsfiddle example above, I need div.content to have height==320px in original example and height==400px when setting 'display' to 'none' in .component CSS rule. It works in FF, but for IE gives height==400px in both cases.