# Make a <textarea> fill remaining height

Tags: css

I learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555820/set-div-to-remaining-height-using-css-with-unknown-height-divs-above-and-below) how to make an HTML element fill the remaining height of a container. But it doesn't seem to be working with `<textarea>`. This Fiddle compares the effects of `display: table-row` on a `<textarea>` and a `<div>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/b4Tt8/2/

Why the difference, and how can I get the appropriate effect on the textarea?

Answer (score 21):

You can use flexbox to set your textarea height according to its parent.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button>X</button>
  </div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
 } 

.container textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* fit parent width */
  height: 100%;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4Tt8/63/)

Comment: The simplest solution, if IE9 support isn't needed :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you set a fixed height to the `button` then you can use positioning and do something like this:

**HTML**:  (*removed br tag*)

```
<div class="container">
    <button>X</button>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button>X</button>
    <div>Text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    height: 220px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: pink;
    display: table;
}
.container > button {
    display: table-row;
}
.container > textarea, .container > div {
    display: table-row;
    border: none;  /* if you keep border then textarea will go out of the parent element */
    height: 200px; /* hardcoded */
    padding: 0px;  /* removing padding for chrome */
    width: 100%;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4Tt8/16/)**

Comment: I forgot you could set multiple position values. I'll probably go with this, but I'm still curious as to why table-row fails for textareas.

Comment: Actually, nevermind - your Fiddle isn't working on Firefox. The textarea is still too small. I'm beginning to think Firefox has some weird issues with textareas.

Comment: @JackM I updated my post using display: table-row as you were trying to achieve before. Check the height: 200px; section again. It might need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `display: table-row;` declarations ? There is no need for this. Remove the `display: table-row;` declarations, add a `box-sizing: border-box;` declaration to your textarea selector and you're all set :

```
.container
{
    height: 220px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: pink; 
}

.container > textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: cyan;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container > div
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4Tt8/10/)

EDIT :

The CSS above makes the text area overflowing its parent div.

Here is an updated answer :

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button>X</button>
    </div>
    <div class="textarea-wrapper">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS 2

```
.container {
    height: 220px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: pink;
    position: absolute;
}
.container textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container > div {
    background-color: cyan;
}
.container .button-wrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 26px;
}
.container .textarea-wrapper {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

### CSS 3 (using calc function)

```
.container {
    height: 220px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: pink;
}
.container textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container > div {
    background-color: cyan;
}
.container .button-wrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 26px;
}
.container .textarea-wrapper {
    background-color: green;
    height: calc(100% - 26px);
}
```

Here are fiddles that shows both solutions :

[CSS 2](http://jsfiddle.net/pjprp/)

[CSS 3](http://jsfiddle.net/6M8nZ/1/)

Comment: The textarea in your Fiddle is too big, at least on my browser. Set its background to transparent to see this. http://jsfiddle.net/b4Tt8/13/