# How to create two rows in a bootstrap without scrolling using one with pixel and another with percentage?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to create two rows in a bootstrap without scrolling using one with pixel and another with percentage ?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row main_header">
        sadf
    </div>
    <div class="row main_second">
        <div class="col-lg-2 main_left">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 main_right">
           test 
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

How to create two rows in a bootstrap without scrolling using one with pixel and another with percentage ?

```
    .main_header{
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #606060;
    color: #fff
}
.main_left{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
} .main_right{
    height: 100%;
    }
.main_second{
     height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If you want it to be 100% of the viewport height use `vh`. So `height: 100vh`.

Comment: still i m getting the vertical scroll bar and is there any way to solve without display:table

Comment: If the content is too long for its containers height there will be a scrollbar. To prevent a scrollbar specify `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Also, if you want both rows to accumatively encompass the full-screen height, on the element you specify 100%, make it 100% minus the other elements height. `height : calc(100% - 80px);`.

Comment: why .row{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    width: 100vh;
} doesnt view it in full width and removing 100vh in row class width is working ?

Comment: For width you would use vw for viewport width. vh stands for viewport height.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use any additional CSS to achieve what you want as Bootstrap already have a very established Grid System. Please see my following example in the following [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/OTWHEscULD)!

All what I have used is the following lines with Twitter Bootstrap V3.3.4:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red;">.col-sm-4</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

And you can add any additional divs within those two divs.
Learn about the Grid System very well to use this via [these kind of tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp).

And it's better to look at the following [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242226/1752988), I guess.

Comment: I believe OP may have been talking about the height of the rows.

Comment: still i m getting the vertical scroll bar and is there any way to solve without display:table